# C# Issue while getting Disk performance values from windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm using following code to get disk performance values from windows PC.

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace DiskPerformance
{
    class Program
    {
        #region Constants
        private const string QUERY = "select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk";
        private const string NAME = "Name";
        private const char COLON = ':';
        private const string READ_PER_SECOND = "DiskReadsPerSec";
        private const string WRITE_PER_SECOND = "DiskWritesPerSec";
        #endregion

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var objMOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(QUERY);
                var collection = objMOS.Get();
                foreach (ManagementObject service in collection)
                {
                    if (!(service.Properties[NAME].Value is String name) ||
                        name.Length != 2 || name[1] != COLON)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    name = name[0].ToString();

                    var diskReadsPerSec = ((UInt32)service.Properties[READ_PER_SECOND].Value);
                    var diskWritesPerSec = ((UInt32)service.Properties[WRITE_PER_SECOND].Value);

                    Console.WriteLine("Disk = {0},  Read per Sec = {1}, Write per Sec = {2}", name, diskReadsPerSec, diskWritesPerSec);
                }

                Console.Read();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code works fine in most of the environments, but it throws following error while using windows 8.1 pro.

> System.Management.ManagementException: Invalid query

I do not get any additional information from stack trace either.

Stack trace :

> System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus
>   errorCode)
>   System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()

Does anyone has any idea what could be the problem?

*PS: I already have administrator privileges and program is executed as admin.*

Comment: What are the *most environments* where it does work? Windows 10? Any other environment?

Comment: @KenWhite I have checked it with windows 10, Windows Server 2014 & Windows Server 2016.All environments are x64.

Comment: That would indicate to me that the functionality does not exist in WIndows 8, and was added in later versions of WMI.

Comment: @KenWhite nowhere on msdn it says that windows 8.1 does not have Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk WMI class.

Comment: Does it say it does have it, though? MS is not in the habit of saying OSes don't have things; they typically define things the OS does have. Where in MSDN does it specifically say that the class is available on WIn 8.1? There are lots of things that were added in Win 10 that did not exist on 8.1.

Comment: @KenWhite I agree with you completely, but do you know of any way that I could use to make sure that WMI class does not exist in windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: Do you have the link to MSDN you're using? It should tell you the minimum OS version needed for that class. What does it say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177313/discussion-between-vishwas-trivedi-and-ken-white).

Comment: window 8 not support System.Management.ManagementException.